# Using Mifare DESFire for authenticating with Android app and lock system

Tags: android, authentication, sdk, nfc, mifare

I have browsed a lot of related questions and answers, have gained approximate understanding on how that might work, but I just need someone pointing me towards the right direction regarding DESFire master and application keys as well the multiple application system.

My questions are as follows:

1. Are the "applications" of DESFire as different real-life
   applications, meaning that an application on DESFire can be mapped
   to a certain real-life application like authenticating personal
   computer, opening doors at your workplace and proceeding with an
   online payment?
2. If so, what should I keep generally in mind designing a solution with DESFire?
3. How should I generate and store the keys? Single card would be used for a booking system at my workplace and opening doors at home. There is no intent of designing a custom NFC-enabled door-lock system, something available on the marked would be used instead. Suggestions of systems are welcome here as well.
4. Door locks have NFC terminals, can someone with experience explain me a bit to what extent the terminals can be configured? Are they just storing the master and application keys or it is possible to define custom authentication algorithm usually? How?

So far I've decided to use the Mifare SDK Advanced for Android to handle the writing and also authenticating the card in one of it's applications. Any opinions on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

DESFIRE card are Storage card.
You could store data in records.
Records are stored in application.

Each card could have 28 applications.
Each application could have 16 files.
File is defined with 5 types:
 - Standard Data Files
 - Backup Data Files
 - Value Files with
 - Linear Record Files with Backup
 - Cyclic Record Files with Backup

All application could be secured by key.

So there's no real life app. But you can store data as you want on it.
For instance data for :

- wallet
- Authentication

Keep in mind, specifications are confidential and you need a NDA to get it.

Comment: Here's the "short" datasheet : http://www.nxp.com/documents/short_data_sheet/MF3ICDX21_41_81_SDS.pdf.

Comment: @kr15h Is it useful ? or you need more info ?

Comment: @LaurentY yes, I would like to have more info. What do you mean by "But you can't create what you want on it:". Are you trying to say that I can't do what I want to do with it?

Comment: @kr15h sorry I made a mistake. "You can store data as you want"

Comment: @LaurentY in your opinion - what would be the best way for creating cards for authentication?

Comment: @kr15h What's amount of information you want to store on card ? 150 bytes or 1Kb or 2Kb or 4Kb,... ?

Comment: @LaurentY Not much. I wonder if I need to store anything on the cards at all. Not more than 2KB for sure.

Comment: @kr15h If you need 2KBytes, I suggest you Desfire 2K

Comment: @LaurentY, thanks. I have that already. Right now I am searching for some tips regarding safe authentication. Do you have experience with that?

Comment: @kr15h, As I already told you specifications are confidential and you need a NDA to get it. There's an open-source library to communicate with Mifare http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libfreefare